# Be sure that never have JQuery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create code which can be used as snipped for every site.
When I copy paste this code to any html in the world this should work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> my_jQuery = $.noConflict(true);</script>
<script type="text/jscript">
        my_jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            my_jQuery("#myDiv").html("Hello world");
        });
</script>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Of Course in real world logic will be more complex but principle is same.

So this must work even if site already have JQuery, if have same version of JQuery,if have different version of JQuery, or even if does not have JQuery at all.

I want be sure that client does not use some old version of JQuery, so I want always use my JQuery.

What do you think, will this work or there is something that I have not consider?

Comment: You could put the snippet in an iFrame

Comment: To keep global namespace unaffected, I'd go with `(function ($) { /* your code */ })(jQuery.noConflict(true));`

Comment: ***NOTE***: `text/jscript` is IE only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this question should be faced in an architectural way, knowing what libraries/frameworks are available is a design concern... Basically, you shouldn't need to check dependencies at runtime... if you write `jQuery`, you must be sure that jQuery exists!

By the way, there are some cases where you can't do it, for example, if you are writing a public/api (a snippet that runs in heterogeneous environments). In these cases, you can do:

1. mark `jQuery` as peer-dependencies
2. Check at runtime.

There is an example of runtime checking:

```html
<script>
  (function($) {
    var jQueryUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js';
    
    $ || (document.writeln('<script src="'+ jQueryUrl +'"></script>'));
    
  })(window.jQuery);
</script>
```

In order to avoid conflicts, finally, you don't need to use `jQuery.noConflict`, you need to work with javascript scopes (closures)... basically, never try to access the global jQuery alias `$` (never use global vars), simple pass it as function param:

1. `(function($) { console.log('$', $); })(window.jQuery)`
2. `window.jQuery(document).ready(function($) { console.log('$', $); });`

Comment: I'm not sure it is that easy. Sometimes you simply have no control over where your code is placed or it could simply be a design decision that the snippet should in fact include the required library (maybe a version thing or similar). In that case `noConflict` is exactly the *tool* to use.

Comment: @Yoshi Yes, I want be sure that client does not use some old version of JQuery, so I want always use my jquery.

Comment: In order to check jQuery version, you can do `jQuery().jquery`... But, I think that loading multiples version of the same library is a very bad thing, instad of doing that, you should warn this information: `if(jQuery().version < MIN_VERSION_SUPPORTED) { throw new Error('jQuery Invalid Version') }`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we need to do is check if jQuery is present on the website. jQuery is the global variable so it should be in window object if it is loaded. We can check it like this: `if (window.jQuery) {}`

If the jQuery not present we can dynamically load it adding script tag with desired jQuery version. So the snippet answering for checking if jQuery is loaded and loading if it's not would be like:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
  var jq = document.createElement('script'); 
      jq.type = 'text/javascript';
      jq.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would work for

1. So this must work even if site already have JQuery,
2. if have same version of JQuery,
3. if have different version of JQuery,
4. <del>or even if does not have JQuery at all</del>.

---

As you can see as per your code, that would work fine for all three situations but 4th one. For this case you have to have a check to find if ***window*** has ***jQuery*** object. That can be done with:

```
if(window.jQuery){
    var my_jQuery = $.noConflict(true);
    my_jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        my_jQuery("#myDiv").html("Hello world");
    });
}
```

#### Note:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
```

would not work in the browsers other than IE.